# PHP JSON does not work, can anyone tell me why?

Tags: php, jquery, json

**myfile.php**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode( array( 'error' => 'jkfshdkfj hskjdfh skld hf.' ) );
```

the above code works.

but when I alter it it stops working:

```
if( isset( $_GET['customerID'] ) ){

       // do something else error

} else {

   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode( array( 'error' => 'jkfshdkfj hskjdfh skld hf.' ) );

}
```

both outputs are correct:

```
{"error":"jkfshdkfj hskjdfh skld hf."}
```

but I get an ajax error:

**myfile.phtml**

```
        <?php 
            if( isset( $_GET['custID'] ) )
               echo "var custID = " . htmlentities( $_GET['custID'] ) . ";";                             
            else
               echo "var custID = null;";                             
        ?>

        $.ajax({

            url: 'php/viewCustomer.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {customerID: custID},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){

                $('#display').append('<div id="loader"> Lodaing ... </div>');

            },
            complete: function(){

                $('#loader').remove();

            },
            success: function( data ){

                if( data.error ) {

                    var errorMessage = "";

                    $.each( data, function( errorIndex, errorValue ){ 

                        errorMessage += errorValue + "\n";

                    });

                    alert( errorMessage );

                } else {

                    //$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(0).text( '1234' );
                    //$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(1).text( '1234' );
                    //$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(2).text( '1234' );
                    //$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(3).text( '1234' );
                    //$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(4).text( '1234' );
                    alert( data );

                }                       

            },
            error: function( jqXHR ){

                alert( 'AJAX ERROR' );

            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: What error do you get? What happens when `customerID` is set?

Comment: The error is 'AJAX ERROR' from the error: function( jqXHR ) { alert( 'AJAX ERROR' ); }

Comment: You are passing a customerID with the ajax request, so it's going into the if - what output are you expecting?

Comment: data: {customerID: custID} = where is the custID coming from?

Comment: Chad, if customerID is set I do nothing at the moment. empty if block.

Comment: Oli, it is currently NULL.

Comment: Tim, json data, but its currently empty.

Comment: So then your php isn't sending back to your ajax script, if that PHP snippet is complete, right?

Comment: @TimFountain Has answered this. Although the value might be null or undefined in javascript, the if condition in php is met. So what do you expect?

Comment: Oli the browser out of myfile.php is {"error":"jkfshdkfj hskjdfh skld hf."}

Comment: hek2, I am getting the output {"error":"shdkfj hskjdfh skld hf."} in myfile.php in the broswer.

Comment: According to your question, myfile.php has 2 different sets of code in it. However you haven't shown us what is in 'php/viewCustomer.php' and this is the script being called by the AJAX routine.

Comment: but you're referencing 'php/viewCustomer.php' in your script..

Comment: Oli, thats not an error, Ive just called it myfile for simplicity.

Comment: Ok glad the 'empty()' is working for you..don't understand how you could still see the error if this fixed it though!

Comment: Oli, I did a bit of amending my self the if block contains   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode( array( 'data' => 'jkfshdkfj hskjdfh skld hf.' ) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like you are passing a null customerID and are not expecting it to go into the if condition. But even if the value is null, `$_GET['customerID']` is still set. Change the check to `empty()` instead and it will work as you expect:

```
if( !empty( $_GET['customerID'] ) ){
    ....
```